# How do you use HTML5 elements in WYGWAM?

Tags: pixelandtonic, wygwam

I see that WYGWAM added support for HTML5 elements (section, figure, etc.) in their changelog, but I cannot figure out how to enable or use them. Can someone enlighten me?

Answer (score 1):

WYGWAM does not have the ability to add HTML5 elements like `<figure>` out of the box. It appears you only have access to features that come out of the box with CK Editor, even though you could build a "Widget" that would give you the ability to add HTML5 elements.